# C# Login system with 'Online/Activity status'?

Tags: c#, android, .net, authentication, web-applications

I'm asking for the best method to go down for creating a login system for my web application. This web application also has an android app I am developing and I have the same question for that login system.

My problem is I would like a status for each user to show whether the user is 'online' or 'offline', and I can't find much information on this topic/understand how it would be done. My C# web application currently uses .net Authentication and connects to SQLServer database for user credentials check to gain access to the app. But I'm unsure how I would be able to ensure a user is 'Online' once logged in and then subsequently 'Offline' if a user is not logged in? I also don't understand how it would work if a user's PC died or the user closes the web application window.

This is the same problem I have in android application, is there any methods that would provide this type of login 'status' for an android application?

Sorry If my English is not the best. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can move forward like this. You add a column called status to the User table. If the user has successfully logged in, you can update the status field online. When you log out, you update the opposite, that is, offline. I guess you will have to write code in javascript to change the status of the user when the page is closed.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply, yes thats the only method I had in my head it just seemed like there wouldve been like a .net built in method. I can see there is methods to handle alt-F4 and clicking X which would all together seem to work but to your knowledge is using this database column solution generally how this is acheived?. for the android side what about if a user is logged in on application and then phone dies.

Comment: You can think of it like this, if alt f4 does it, you can write an endpoint that catches the user and disables the user. I haven't dealt with Android before, but there may be a method like this. Do a search of the Android life cycle. If the user has returned to the main menu from the application, find its life cycle and perform operations here

Comment: THANK YOU ALL, I believe now can attempt to implement this 'Status' feature with high robustness. I very much appreciate the comments and answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the user to be online when the mouse is active, and update database every 10 minutes, if the user is not active for 10 minutes it will automatically mark as away.

Comment: One is required to use a mouse or be logged out?

Comment: You can use mouse events.

Answer (score 1):

Add the column as Bayram suggested.

Add another column "lastKeepAlive" that is a date. Update the column at fitting intervals in code and/or on user activity.

If the date is older than X the user is offline, and can be set to offline. "lastKeepAlive" could be updated.

Either implement in app code of a process that runs separately.